# Installing/Linking libwebsockets library in AWS Linux for mosquitto MQTT

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cmake, mqtt, libwebsockets

Following the AWS Guide: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/how-to-bridge-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-to-aws-iot/ and I got to the step that has me install mosquitto.

`//Update the list of repositories with one containing Mosquitto
sudo wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/oojah:/mqtt/CentOS_CentOS-7/home:oojah:mqtt.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/mqtt.repo
//Install Mosquitto broker and Mosquitto command line tools
sudo yum install mosquitto mosquitto-clients`

However, the guide is so outdated that it does not mention anything about the missing libwebsockets library. I've spent roughly 4-5 hours on searching for an answer on how to manually install/link/setup the library but I have not been able to make anything work.

(1) Tried this
`git clone https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets.git
cd libwebsockets
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc
make
sudo make install`

But yea that didn't work because CMAKE throws all kinds of errors like

`CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:99 (message):   Could not find toolchain file: /tmp/mytoolchainfile
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:131 (project)
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /tmp/libwebsockets/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`

So I tried to set the CMAKE_C_COMPILER path to /usr/bin/gcc, which is where the compiler is installed and that didn't do anything either. In all honesty, I'm not super familiar with Linux, I'm just trying to make do the best I can. I could really use some guidance on how best to get library installed and linked into Linux. I do believe AWS runs a red-hat version of linux.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I had this working using aws linux 2

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm -P /tmp
sudo yum install -y /tmp/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm 
sudo yum install libwebsockets
sudo yum install mosquitto mosquitto-clients
```